# VB error when using date for a search criteria

Tags: sql, vb.net, date

Getting this error

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter[] objects

When trying to search for records with dates

```
Public Function GetSelectedLog(Optional ByVal FileNumber As String = Nothing, _
                               Optional ByVal dateFrom As Date = Nothing, _
                               Optional ByVal dateTo As Date = Nothing) As DataView
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("GetSelectedLog", objCommon.sqlCon)
        Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter
        adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim sqlParam(2) As SqlParameter

        sqlParam(0) = New SqlParameter("@FileNumber", IIf(FileNumber Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, FileNumber))
        If dateFrom <> DateTime.MinValue Then
            sqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter("@dateFrom", dateFrom)
        Else
            sqlParam(1) = New SqlParameter("@dateFrom", DBNull.Value)
        End If
        If dateTo <> DateTime.MinValue Then
            sqlParam(2) = New SqlParameter("@dateTo", dateTo)
        Else
            sqlParam(2) = New SqlParameter("@dateTo", DBNull.Value)
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam)

        If objCommon.sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then objCommon.sqlCon.Open()
        adp.Fill(ds)
        Return ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        objCommon.sqlCon.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: were you going to add more information to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear.  You are trying to pass an array of SqlParameter to the Add method:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam)
```

Perhaps you meant to use AddRange instead?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParam)
```

Comment: +1. I have deleted my answer. Though my answer contained relevent info, it was not the actual reason.